# How to build an infinite series function of x and y?

Tags: python, function, sympy, physics

Basically what it says in the title. I'm trying to graph the exact solution of a differential equation with certain boundary conditions, as compared to an approximation found with the principle of variation. However, the exact solution is an infinite series, which I am trying to build as a function of x and y using sympy. The series function is written both inside and outside phi_exact because my instructor says it is not good form to put functions within other functions, but sometimes that's the only way I can make them work. I'm working in Python since that's the only computer language I'm even remotely familiar with. Here is the code I wrote:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sympy as sym

e_0 = 8.85e-12 #vacuum permittivity epsilon-nought
k_e = 1/(4*sym.pi*e_0) #defining the Coulomb constant to save space
pi = sym.pi

#Set variational solution
A = 5/(4*e_0) #coefficient we found analytically
def phi_var(x,y):
  psi = A*x*(1-x)*y*(1-y) #form of the variational solution
  return psi

#Set exact solution
def finite_series(x,y,N):
  coeff = 16*k_e / (np.pi)**2 #prefactor, absorbing 1/4pi*e0
  total = 0 #dummy variable
  upper_bound = N
  for m in range(1, upper_bound): #spelling out the mth term
    n = 2*m + 1 #summing over only odd numbers
    trig = np.sin(n*pi*x)
    denom = n**3
    ratio = (np.cosh(n*pi*(y-1/2)))/(np.cosh(n*pi/2))
    m_term = (trig/denom)*(1-ratio)
    total += m_term
  return total

def phi_exact(x,y): #exact potential as a function of x and y
  def total(x,y,N):
    coeff = 16*k_e / pi**2 #prefactor, absorbing 1/4pi*e0
    total = 0 #dummy variable
    upper_bound = int(N)
    for m in range(1, upper_bound): #spelling out the mth term
      n = 2*m + 1 #summing over only odd numbers
      trig = np.sin(n*pi*x)
      denom = n**3
      ratio = (np.cosh(n*pi*(y-1/2)))/(np.cosh(n*pi/2))
      m_term = (trig/denom)*(1-ratio)
      total += m_term
    return total
  exact = total(x,y,N)
  return coeff*sym.series.limits.limit(total, N, sym.oo) #limit as the # of terms --> oo
print(phi_exact(1,0))
```

I looked up the documentation for infinite series in sympy and tried to insert a function of x and y as the summand. It returns an error, however, in the "**for** m..." line that "function object cannot be interpreted as integer." So I tried setting a new variable upper_bound to equal (the value of) the function parameter N, since that has fixed similar problems for me in the past, but that still doesn't fix this particular problem. So how do I fix this problem? N, the upper limit of the partial sum, needs to be defined as part of the series solution before I can take the limit as N-->oo. Any advice would be great!

Comment: Hi! I strongly, strongly encourage you **not** to use `sum` as the name of one of your variables. `sum` is the name of a builtin function in python, and if you shadow that name by using it for your own variable, not only do you lose access to `sum`, but if you use a function that uses `sum` internally, things will go weird.

Comment: Actually, your main bug is due to shadowing too. You wrote `from sympy import *` instead of just `import sympy`, which means all things from sympy are imported into the main namespace. One of these things is called `series`. But you defined your own function named `series` when you wrote `def series(...): ....`. So now the big sympy submodule named `series` is inaccessible because it's hidden by your function that has the same name. When you wrote `series.limits.limit(...)`, you're not calling a sympy function, because `series` now refers to your own function `series`.

Comment: Also, there is no good reason to use `np.pi` instead of `sympy.pi`.

Comment: @Stef Good to know. I'm just getting back into coding after a few years, so sometimes I make clueless mistakes like that. I went back and fixed the sum/sympy issue, but unfortunately that still doesn't solve the issue of Python not liking a "for" loop with the upper bound being a variable in the outer function. Do you know what might work for that?

Comment: I think the issue you describe is also related to these namespace issues. If you read the code that you've posted in your question, there is no definition of `N` anywhere. So when you write `exact = series(x,y,N)`, what do you think happens? Normally you should expect python to complain `NameError: name 'N' is not defined`. But in this case instead you get `TypeError: 'function' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`. This is because [sympy defines a function named `N`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/evalf.html). Since you wrote `from sympy import *`, now `N` is that function.

Comment: Also at the end I believe you should use [sympy.series.limitseq](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/series/limitseq.html), not `sympy.series.limits`? I cannot find any object called `sympy.series.limits` in the documentation, and indeed I get `AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'limits'` if I try to write `sympy.series.limits` in python.

Comment: Also note in your function you define `coeff = 16*k_e / (np.pi)**2` but then you don't use `coeff` anywhere in the calculation.

Comment: @Stef I fixed the namespace issue (I think); the edits can be seen above. However, it's still returning a NameError, and when I try `sym.series.limitseq.limit_seq(1/n,n)` per the documentation (which should tend to 0 as n-->oo), Python complains that the 'function' object has no attribute 'limitseq.'